# Saving emails to list

Tags: list, email

I want to add emails to list but didn't find the default one. Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the list you can save emails to them. If you mean emailing to a list then that is possible with announcements and discussion boards. Here's how to set that up:

1. Go to the List that you want to save emails to.
2. Go to the List tab under List Tools -> click List Settings
3. Click the Incoming e-mail settings
4. Select Yes under "Allow this list to receive e-mail"
5. Select Yes to "Save Original Email" and click OK. Make sure the user that is sending the email has access, if not, select "Accept e-mail messages from any sender"

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the SharePoint Outlook Connector on CodePlex?

http://spoutlookconnector.codeplex.com/